# Probability Theory Question (Bayes Theorem)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am stuck at this question. I am trying to use Bayes Theorem for it and the try imagining $10,000$ technique but still can't seem to solve it.

A test for a disease is $95$% accurate if the disease is present, and $99$% accurate if it is absent. $5$% of the population have the disease.

(a)  In a sample of $4$ people, what is the probability that one actually has the disease?
(b)  For the same sample, what is the probability that at least one person actually has the disease?

Comment: I think you are missing something in the wording of your question, probably about testing positive

Comment: That is what I have been provided with.

Comment: But then the information about the test's accuracy is irrelevant. Are you sure this is exactly the problem's wording?

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: I am new to this site and won't repeat the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well assuming its worded correctly (it's not)

a) With 4 people, the probability that one has the disease, is 3 of them not having it, and 1 having it. Multiplied by the number of ways you could pick one of them to have it

$\binom{4}{1}.95^3.05 = .17$

b) The probability that at least 1 person has the disease, is 1 - (probability no one has disease)

$1 - .95^4 = .8145$

Comment: Many thanks, I think it can be solved via binomial formula.